# SQL Query by using with

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query...

------ create table

```
create table test222
(
    sid bigint, 
    scode nvarchar(50), 
    parentid bigint, 
    sname nvarchar(50)
)

insert into test222 values (1, '11', 0, 'iam a boy')
insert into test222 values (2, '111', 1, 'boy')
insert into test222 values (3, '1111', 1, 'bo')
insert into test222 values (4, '11111', 3, 'girl')

insert into test222 values (5, '111111', 0, 'boyy')
insert into test222 values (6, '1111111', 5, 'gril')


insert into test222 values (7, '22', 0, 'body')
insert into test222 values (8, '222', 7, 'girll')
```

following is my code,,,

```
;WITH SInfo AS
(
    SELECT
        t.sId,
        t.scode,
        t.ParentId,
        t.sName,
        CONVERT(nvarchar(800), t.scode) AS Hierarchy,
        t.ParentId as HParentId
    FROM test222 as t
    WHERE
        t.sname like '%bo%'

    UNION    ALL

    SELECT
        si.sId,
        si.scode,
        si.ParentId,
        si.sName,
        CONVERT(nvarchar(800), TH.scode + '\' + si.Hierarchy),
        th.parentid
    FROM SInfo as si
    INNER JOIN test222 TH
        ON TH.sId = si.HParentId
)

Select t.sId, t.scode, t.ParentId, t.sName, t.Hierarchy
from SInfo as t
where
    HParentId = 0 and
    not exists (select 1 from SInfo as s
                where
                    s.sid <> t.sid and
                    s.Hierarchy like t.Hierarchy + '%')
```

the op generated is shown below

```
5    111111    0    boyy    111111
7    22        0    body    22
3    1111      1    bo      11\1111
```

the third row is not correct

It should be

```
3    111111    1    bo    11\111\1111.
```

How can i do that???

Comment: This seems to be a MS SQL Server question, could you tag it correctly? And could you please describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: Record `3, 1111, 1, bo` has record `1, 11, 0, iam a boy` as its parent. Latter record is a root record, hence the result seems to be ok.

Comment: yes thats correct, but i want the full path, what i am getting is just the first and the last record only.. i want the full path 11\111\1111 even other fields are not that important, i just want the hierarchy,, thats it

Comment: `11\1111` *is* the full path from record `3, 1111, 1, bo` up to the root record, i.e. `1, 11, 0, iam a boy`. There are no other records between those two according to the sample data you posted.

Comment: insert into test222 values (1, '11', 0, 'iam a boy')insert into test222 values (2, '111', 1, 'boy')insert into test222 values (3, '1111', 2, 'boo')
insert into test222 values (4, '11111', 2, 'bo')insert into test222 values (5, '111111', 0, 'boyy')insert into test222 values (6, '1111111', 5, 'gril')
insert into test222 values (7, '22', 5, 'body')insert into test222 values (8, '222', 0, 'girll')insert into test222 values (9, '33', 8, 'boy')insert into test222 values (10, '333', 9, 'bo') op expected is as follows
11\111\1111-11111

111111\22

222\33\333

Comment: Your query returns exactly what you want, see fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fca49/1/0

Comment: no its not correct...what i want is 11\111\1111-11111(2 childs) (ur code is correct except this line))) ( pls help me))

111111\22

222\33\333

Comment: no its not correct...what i want is 11\111\1111-11111(2 childs)

Comment: guys, can some one help me???

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the parent id of the record - sid=3 to its chronological parent instead of its grand parent :-) . Check below.

Change

```
insert into #test222 values (3, '1111', 1, 'bo')
```

to

```
insert into #test222 values (3, '1111', 2, 'bo')
```

The reason you are not seeing the middle portion (record - sid:2) is because record - sid=2 and record - sid=3 essentially share the same "FROM" criteria. sname= '%bo%' (or rather LIKE '%bo%') and parentid=1. The record - sid=3 is the last record in the set with this shared "FROM" criteria and hence is the record being returned.

Order of SQL query execution (FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, SELECT, ORDER BY)

[Here is a link to recursive CTE queries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.